# Fontify shell commands in org example

Tags: org-mode, font-lock

I'd like to write examples of shell commands in an Org document:

```
Here's an inlined ~if~ statement:
#+begin_example
  $ if true; then echo hello; fi
  hello
#+end_example
```

I wish for the command part, starting with `$`, to be fontified as in `shell-script-mode`.  Is there a way to do this?  For instance, by creating a major mode deriving from `shell-script-mode` that *only* looks at lines starting with `$`?  Or by tricking `font-lock` into thinking that `$` is a single character comment and lines starting with anything but `$` are comments?

Comment: I got you, there should be a major-mode for it, named like "shell-history-mode" maybe? I looked for this several times. If you care only about exporting, there is "shell session" support in https://prismjs.com/

Comment: @nichijou: Neat! I added an advice to `org-html-fontify-code` to add `<code class="language-shell-session">`, and it looks nifty.  Thanks!  I'll keep the question open since I'd prefer a solution within Org, but in the meantime, this definitely helps!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: update w.r.t. comments

So the final solution/workaround is:

- use source blocks, as they include highlighting when exported
- comment out, i.e. put `#` before, the self written output lines
- then in the function `org-html-src-block` replace the line

```lisp
(code (org-html-format-code src-block info))
```

with

```lisp
       (code (with-temp-buffer (insert (org-html-format-code src-block info))
                                   (goto-char (point-min))
                                   (while (not (eobp))
                                     (print (search-forward ">"))
                                     (if (looking-at "# ")
                                         (replace-match "")
                                       (insert "$ "))
                                     (forward-line))
                                   (print (buffer-string))))
```

(where the `search-forward` code probably has to get slightly improved for inputs without fontification)

END EDIT

I think you should use a source block for this instead, e.g. as follows

```bash
#+begin_src sh :exports both
  if true; then echo hello; fi
#+end_src
```

You will get the output by running/exporting it (the `:exports both` header argument makes that both the code and the result get exported).

Then subsequently you can format exported output how you prefer it. You can define a derived backend for this (so I guess you should create e.g. `my-sh` source blocks).

You can read more about it [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html) and [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-export-reference.html). Especially check out the function `org-export-define-derived-backend` in the latter link. You can then set your personal `my-org-html-src-block` translator function (that you can adapt from the original `org-html-src-block` function) for source blocks in the `:translate-alist`. (To understand the code in the `org-html-src-block` function, I would recommend to use `edebug`. I guess you can get rid of most of the code, and just keep and modify 'the essence' of it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I believe this is "avoiding" my main problem, by changing my input.  I'd very much rather keep my blocks as they are right now, with inputs and outputs written by me.  Most of them contain multiple commands, a good portion use the standard input, and all of this would be a pain to do with Org (if doable at all).

Comment: That's fine of course. However, I don't think multiple commands per se are a problem in org. And also I am wondering what you mean with the commands using stdin. How you use stdin in example blocks?

Comment: Oh, well, it's as in a shell prompt.  Something like:
```$ sed s/i/a/
input
anput
[Ctrl-d]```
If you want to have a quick look at my document, it's there: https://mc.cdm.depaul.edu/sysII/shelllab.html

Comment: That is a great document! So did you already find out the answer to this question (your document looks like you might have)? Otherwise, how do you get the highlighted example blocks? You did not declare a language in the header of your example block in your example (I wasn't aware that this works with example blocks, otherwise I might have given another answer, so I think you should add it to your example here). But even with the language in the header, I don't know how you get it exported including the highlighting (maybe you could add your solution to your question).

Comment: I don't know your exact motivation for this question. But to get the behavior in your exports, as a workaround, you could replace the `$ ` in your examples e.g. with `; ` (which does not mess up the fontification) and then add a regexp-replace at the end of `org-html-example-block` to replace the `; ` at the beginning of lines with `$ `.

Comment: As the example block does not seem to include highlighting in the export, you could simply change them to source blocks (you can still type your own outputs, just don't eval them, i.e. do not include `:exports both`). Of course then you have to move the final regexp-replace to the `org-html-src-block` function.

Comment: Just replace the: ```(code (org-html-format-code src-block info))``` with
```(code (let ((fs (org-html-format-code src-block info))) (replace-regexp-in-string "^; " "$ " fs)))``` in that function. Of course this is just a workaround (which seems to work fine for exports), it would be great if someone could provide a direct answer to the question.

Comment: Okay, I now read again the comments under your question... that is a nice solution too of course for the exports...

Comment: Thanks for diving into this!  In your solution, hod do you prevent the outputs to be formatted?  I think your approach would work if I prefixed every output line with `#`, every input line without `#`, and then add the `$` to non-`#` lines and removed the `#` from the lines that have it.  That's an interesting, less invasive method, I could work with that, thanks! :-)  Let's see if someone comes up with an easy way to write a `shell-session-mode`, but otherwise, that would be an acceptable answer.  (In my document, I use Prism.)

Comment: Ah yes, I 'neglected' the outputs indeed (wrongly, or better lazily, assuming that they would all be 'simple'). But you have already found the better 'alternative' solution. Thanks for your document also... it looks very useful.